# Merge [breaker-box] with [electrical-panel]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The [breaker-box] tag should be a synonym of [electrical-panel] -- "breaker box"/"fuse box" is merely a colloquialism for "electrical panel" (which in turn is a shorthand for "electrical panelboard" :P)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the suggestion. I've made [electrical-panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-panel) the master with [breaker-box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaker-box) and [distribution-board](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-board) as synonyms. Give them some upvotes on the [electrical-panel synonym list](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/electrical-panel/synonyms) if they look good to you.